# about Dirichlet test in convergence

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

whether this infinite sequence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^ncos(nx)}{\sqrt n}$ converge  on $\mathbb R$. I know that it would converge uniformly intuitivly on [$-\pi+\delta$, $\pi-\delta$] where $\delta$ is from $-\pi$ to $\pi$. However, I don't know how to prove my intuition. Thanks for helping.

Comment: My guess is that that $i=0$ should be $n=1$.

Comment: sorry, I type a wrong number

Comment: You have changed the $0$ into a $1$, but you have kept the $i$.

Comment: sorry sorry, i would edit it right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, for any $N\in\mathbb N$, and $x$ in such an interval,\begin{align}\left\lvert\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^n\cos(nx)\right\rvert&=\left\lvert\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^n\operatorname{Re}(e^{inx})\right\rvert\\&=\left\lvert\operatorname{Re}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N(-e^{ix})^n\right)\right\rvert\\&=\left\lvert\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{-e^{ix}-(-1)^{N+1}e^{(N+1)ix}}{1+e^{ix}}\right)\right\rvert\\&\leqslant\left\lvert\frac{-e^{ix}-(-1)^{N+1}e^{(N+1)ix}}{1+e^{ix}}\right\rvert\\&\leqslant\frac2{\bigl\lvert1+e^{ix}\bigr\rvert}.\end{align}Can you take it from here?

Comment: can i ask why $(-1)^{n}$ vanishes in third equality?

Comment: I made a mistake and I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is correct now.

Comment: I think that $e^{(N+1)ix}$ should be $e^{Nix}$ at the fourth equality

Comment: Sure. You are right.

Comment: sorry, i think i'm wrong

Comment: and i think that eventually it would be smaller than $\frac{2}{|1+cosx|}$. This would certainly be the reason why it couldn't converge at $\pi$. Am i right?

Comment: I don't know whether or not it is smaller than $\left\lvert\frac1{1+\cos x}\right\rvert$ and I made no mention of convergence at $\pi$. All that I cared about was the uniform convergence on some interval $[-\pi+\delta,\pi-\delta]$.

Comment: I think I get what you're talking about. I want to know why we can't get uniform convergence at $\pi$, not just by taking $x$ equal to $\pi$. Now, i think it should just take $x$ equal to $\pi$, and then we could know why it won't converge.

Comment: If $x=\pi$, then your series is just $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt n}$, which diverges.

Comment: Thank you. I get it, and this is a good experience for learning how to apply Dirichlet test.

Comment: Have i marked? since i just use this web asking questions a few times, i really don't know how to mark it.

Comment: Yes, it is marked. Thank you.